# Is 2moons Expedition dead?

Tags: 2moons

I used to play an mmorpg back in 2006-2007 called 2moons Expedition. Wanting to relive the past today, I googled it, but can't find the website for this nor the game client. The last time people posted about 2moons was back in 2008.

Last I remember, the game was closed beta and there was going to be no reset/wipe when the real version was launched.

What happened to this game? Is my account gone forever?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Acclaim Games](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acclaim_Games) (the company behind 2Moons) went out of business in late 2010 and most of their games were also shut down, including 2Moons.

You could however try [Dekaron](http://en.dekaron.nexoneu.com/NXEU.aspx), which is the Korean MMO that 2Moons was based on.

Comment: You beat me to it - this is what my research turned up.